# How to hold all lines in a defined environment?

Tags: page-breaking, environments, paragraphs

```
\def\Grammercaption{\textbf{Grammer}}
\def\grammer{\bgroup\ignorespaces\Grammercaption\fontsize{10}{13pt}\selectfont}
\def\grammer{\egroup}
```

I want all lines of text within this environment stick  together. So that no page break is issued here.

Comment: You might be after something like `\newenvironment{grammer}{\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}\Grammercaption\fontsize{10}{13pt}\selectfont}{\endminipage}` that you can then use as `\begin{grammer}`...`\end{grammer}`.

Comment: I also recommend using the `minipage` environment. You may have to tweak the `\parindent` setting inside the `minipage` environment because `minipage` sets it to `opt`.